# How to set {locale} in every URL in Symfony 2?

Tags: php, localization, internationalization, symfony

How do you do that? But avoid it for a specific language if possible

Having to write it for each url is annoying..

Eg: I want my site to respond to / and /fr-FR/ for every url. The former for english, the latter for french.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should take a look at the [JMSI18nRoutingBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSI18nRoutingBundle), it add internationalization support to routes without having to duplicate any routing definition.

This bundle comes configured with three commons scenario for translating routes. Your example is a perfect fit for the [Scenario 2](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSI18nRoutingBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.rst) which is `"Prefixing All Routes With The Locale except those of the default locale"`

Comment: +1, I can't recommend this bundle highly enough. It handles all routes automatically and is flexible enough to work with authentication

Answer (score 1):

In your routing.yml, you might have something like (if youre using yaml for routing configuration:

```
AcmeTestBundle:
  resource: "@AcmeTestBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
  prefix: /
```

Have you tried adding {locale} to the prefix?